# Empty output file after executing Rprof()

Tags: r, profiling

Recently, I became aware of the `Rprof()` function. I tried running various examples, but none of them seems to be working. Below I am giving you one of them:

Script I run in R:

```
# Turn on the profiler. By default it will write its output
# to a file called Rprof.out in my R directory
Rprof()

# code to be profiled
y <- c(4.17,5.58,5.18,6.11,4.50,4.61,5.17,4.53,5.33,5.14)
x <- c(4.81,4.17,4.41,3.59,5.87,3.83,6.03,4.89,4.32,4.69)
lm(y ~ x)

# Turn off the profiler
Rprof(NULL)

# getting a summary of the output
summaryRprof()
$by.self
[1] self.time  self.pct   total.time total.pct 
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

$by.total
[1] total.time total.pct  self.time  self.pct  
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

$sample.interval
[1] 0.02

$sampling.time
[1] 0
```

Furthermore, when I open the Rprof.out file in r, it only has one line which is the following:

> sample.interval=20000

I would appreciate any help on what I am doing wrong, since the output I would have expected should not have been 0 rows, but should have the `lm`, l`mfit` and all the other functions in the `lm` call stack.

I am using Rx64 3.3.1 (through R studio) and my OS is Windows 10 64 bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code runs in less than the sample interval (20 milliseconds), so there are no results.

Comment: Thanks Joshua. I did try a more complex code and the summary returned a meaningful output (different than 0 rows) this time.